# Web Bluetooth cannot detect my Mobile phone (Galaxy Note 9)

Tags: javascript, mobile, bluetooth-lowenergy, progressive-web-apps, web-bluetooth

I am testing web blue tooth through

https://whatwebcando.today/bluetooth.html

one of the use cases there is from the browser, it should be able to detect BLE devices and extract the battery service, which should provide a facility to determine battery level of bluetooth connected device,

However during scanning, the site cannot detect my mobile phone, I have read that Web bluetooth only supports BLE

is this compatibility issues? Upon reading i see that Blue tooth 5 of galaxy note9 is supports BLE or am i wrong?

Comment: Have you tried pairing your mobile phone to the device running the browser?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, [Galaxy Note 9 supports BLE](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2018/8/9/17660828/samsung-galaxy-note-9-s-pen-stylus-bluetooth-features-specs-2018). As per to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web), even though the Web Bluetooth API specification is not finalized yet, the Google Chrome team still in progress for the implementation. It is suggested to use the `navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice` function that takes a mandatory Object that defines filters. These filters are used to return only devices that match some advertised Bluetooth GATT services and/or the device name. From this, you can check if your device is compatible with [Web Bluetooth API specification](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/).

Answer (score 0):

Your phone does not advertise BLE packets automatically. You should have an app that starts BLE advertising.

Answer (score 0):

Your Phone needs to simulate a BLE device and send advertisements of the specific service. In this case the batter_service.

You can use the [BLE Peripheral Simulater](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/ble-test-peripheral-android) for testing